# Dynamics 365 Data Entity Package Manifest Query Data Encoding

Tags: manifest, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

When integrating data with DFO365 we use Data Projects to integrate data from other systems.  Definitions for these projects can be exported; giving a zip file containing multiple XML files; one per data entity in the project, a `PackageHeader.xml`, and a `Manifest.xml` file. Within the manifest file is an element called `QueryData`, which seems to be a byte array held as a string.

The QueryData field looks like this:

```
<QueryData>4a012f270000110001e649010000000a4de9030000862b00008c2b0000882b00
008b2b0000000084045400610078005600410054004e0075006d005400610062
006c00650045006e0074006900740079000000110001e8032e00540061007800
5600410054004e0075006d005400610062006c00650045006e00740069007400
79005f0031000000e2092a005400610078005600410054004e0075006d005400
610062006c00650045006e0074006900740079000000094de8030000f3190000
00920402001100010000ffffffffffffffff9b04ffff9a04ffff000000000000
01ffffffff009005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000</QueryData>
```

I tried treating this as a byte encoded string with some success; i.e. the below PowerShell converts the above code to:

```
Ŋ✯ ŉ ਀蘀+谀+蠀+謀+ 萀各愀砀嘀䄀吀一甀洀吀愀戀氀攀䔀渀琀椀琀礀 ᄀĀϨ.TaxVATNumTableEntity_1 ৢ*TaxVATNumTableEntity 䴉Ϩ ᧳ 鈀ȄᄀĀ қҚ   ！ÿ֐              �
```

So is partially successful; i.e. confirms that the package relates to VAT Numbers.  I'm wondering if anyone knows anything more about the structure of this field to make the rest of the query readable; since this will allow me to compare projects held in source control in a human-readable way.

I understand that binary data isn't always readable / requires specific knowledge of the code which is designed to handle it to be readable; just wondering if anyone has that knowledge.  I have other solutions (e.g. importing old data projects into DFO365 to compare their definitions), but if I can do something via code, that will simplify & speed up such tasks.

PowerShell to Convert QueryData to String

```
clear-host
$x = @'
4a012f270000110001e649010000000a4de9030000862b00008c2b0000882b00
    008b2b0000000084045400610078005600410054004e0075006d005400610062
    006c00650045006e0074006900740079000000110001e8032e00540061007800
    5600410054004e0075006d005400610062006c00650045006e00740069007400
    79005f0031000000e2092a005400610078005600410054004e0075006d005400
    610062006c00650045006e0074006900740079000000094de8030000f3190000
    00920402001100010000ffffffffffffffff9b04ffff9a04ffff000000000000
    01ffffffff009005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000
'@ -replace '\s+','' 
[byte[]]$arr = 0..(($x.Length / 2)-2) | %{ [Convert]::ToByte($x.Substring((2*$_),2),16) } 

[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetChars($arr) -join ''
```